# SSIS Create Tables based on filename

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to import a number of files using SSIS and store each one in a separate table, using their file names as table names.

I know I have to use the For each Loop Container but I'm stuck on passing the file name variable to a create table statement.

I'm sure I can't be the only person to try to do this, but I couldn't find any good examples.

Comment: have a look here [`Loop through Flat Files in SQL Server Integration Services`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: I strongly suggest you simply add another column to _one_ table to hold the filename rather than splitting into multiple named tables.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but I need to integrate with existing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/456f2201-447c-41b3-bf27-b3ba47e6b737/dynamically-creating-sql-tables-in-ssis-foreachloop

FROM THE LINK:
If you are using a For Each loop, you should be able to add an Execute SQL Task to create the table. You'd need to use an expression on the SqlStatement property of the Execute SQL Task to generate the CREATE TABLE syntax dynamically ("CREATE TABLE " + @User::YourFileNameVar...).

In the data flow, change the OLE DB Destination to get the table name from a variable, and use the same variable as above. You'll probably also need to set the DelayValidation property to TRUE on the data flow.

Comment: OK I added the statement to the SqlStatemnetSource under Expressions of the Execute SQL tasks. Thanks for your help, especially the DelayValidation property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using an ExecuteSql task. If so one way of achieving this is by using an Ado.Net connection in your task. You need to map your filename variable in the component and after that you can use the variable inside the task in a dynamic SQL for creating the table.